# jQuery serializeArray doesn't include the submit button that was submit

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I was trying to send a form data to php code some how when I have condition of if the button was submit do the following code it doesn't work :

```
$("button#send").click(function() {

    var error = '';
    var send = $("#send").val() = true;
    if ($('#username').val().length == 0) { error += 'user name<br />'; }
    if ($('#password').val().length == 0) { error += 'password<br />'; }
    if ($('#repassword').val().length == 0) { error += 'repassword<br />'; }
    if ($('#password').val() != $('#repassword').val()) { error += 'pass match<br />'; }
    var phonenum = $('#phonenum').val() + $('#select').val();
    if (phonenum.length == 0) { error += 'phone num <br />'; } else if ($.isNumeric(phonenum) == false || phonenum.length != 10) { error += 'phoneworng<br />'; }


    if (error != '') {
        $('#result').html(error);
    } else {

        $.ajax({
            url: $("#form_reg").attr('action'),
            data: $("#form_reg input").serializeArray(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(result) {
                $("#result").html(result);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(error);
            }

        });


    }
    $("#form_reg").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventdefault;
        return false;
    });
});
```

here the html code

```
<form id="form_reg" action="AddUser.php" method="post">
    <div class="head_div"> <span> reg </span> </div>
    <div id="main_reg">
        <div class="login_line">
            <label for="username">username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username" />
        </div>
        <div class="login_line">
            <label for="password"> passs </label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="pass" />
        </div>
        <div class="login_line">
            <label for="repassword"> repass </label>
            <input type="password" name="repassword" id="repassword" placeholder="repass" />
        </div>
        <div class="login_line">
            <label for="email"> email </label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="login_line">
            <label for="phonenum"> phone num</label>
        </div>
        <div class="login_line">
            <input type="text" id="phonenum" name="phonenum" placeholder="phone num" />
            <select id="select">
                <option value="050"> 050</option>
                <option value="054"> 054</option>
                <option value="052"> 052</option>
                <option value="053"> 053</option>
                <option value="058"> 058</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="login_line">
        <div id="result"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="send_line">
        <button type="submit" name="send" id="send"> reg</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

here the php

```
include_once 'login_db.php';
    $error_msg="";
    if(isset($_POST['send']))
    {
```

And the rest there include the echo somehow without the `if isset($_POST['send'])`
the code is echo the result

Comment: If you are submitting the form contents via ajax - you will need to prevent the normal form submission via the submit button click - otherwise that button will trigger the form submit and there will be nothing to submit via the ajax call and so the isset condition will fail.

Comment: It wouldn't send the submit since that's only sent when submitted via click. You can add a hidden input that repeats the same name/value though. Also `e.preventDefault();` (it's a function)

Comment: @ apokryfos  is it securty to do that and what value i put there?

Comment: Just check for any of the other post parameters you expect to receive in any case, or just the request method (S_SERVER array) ... later on you're validating if all parameters are set and have correct values anyway, right?